# Changing the name of a payment processor on the front end

Tags: civievent, payment-processor

Would it be possible to change the name of a payment processor in the event registration screen? 
When a new attendee is registering for event under Payment Options > Payment Method they see the radio buttons for the available payment processors such as Paypal or Stripe. I want to change the text for the Stripe option to be Credit Card. Our user base doesn't know what Stripe is and it would helpful if it was more general than the actual name of the credit card processor. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this. 2 easiest

1) Change the name of the payment processor in /civicrm/admin/paymentProcessor

The problem with this approach is it becomes less clear to you the administrator.

2) A *hack*, go to your current registration page where the radio buttons to choose payment processor appear. Find the < div > tag that encompasses both using your browsers debug tools(right click, inspect element). Record the id(id="xxx") of that div.

in the confirmation screen or registration screen(which screen do the radio buttons appear on in your event) open the the WYSIWYG editor for introductory text and  **click on the source button**.

Then, enter the following javascript. at the very top, above any text you may have entered.(replace xxx with id you found before)

```
<script type="javascript/text">
    var divOfInterest = document.findElementById("xxx");
    var replacements = {"Stripe":"CreditCard", "Paypal":"Your Paypal Account", "payment3":"betterlabel"};

    for (var toReplace in replacements) {
        divOfInterest.innerHTML = divOfInterest.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replacements[toReplace]);
    }

</script>
```

Again, make sure you clicked the 'source' button on the WYSIWYG editor. Also, make sure you are adding your javascript to the correct Intro text(prob in registration or confirmation)

Note: this will replace any instance of the word "Stripe" with credit card in that < div >.